# Is WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP still necessary for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

For WP80, I had been using -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP when compiling C++ code. Is this still necessary? Should I be using WINAPI_FAMILY_APP instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, still required.  In WP8.1, phone API partition is still different than that of Windows Store apps.  This is how a default VS2013 Phone 8.1 project settings look like:

[image]